# How to move text from one page into the form of another page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a page with information on it, let's say

```
<p>username=test</p>
<p>password=test2</p>
```

i need to search through this page, find the value for username and the value for password, store them, probably in a variable. and carry them over onto a form on another page. like so:

```
Username: <input type="text" name="Username"><br />
Password: <input type="text" name="Password">
```

This second page i would very much like to not be on the same server. so using php POST is a tad out of the question, and i dont think you can carry variables between pages with javascript. Anyone have any ideas?

note:also, i have no access to the code on the other server, (the form) however i understand that js can be ran out of the url bar, so perhaps i could use this to fill in the textboxes.

Comment: Why can't you use php POST?

Comment: Username and Password are a bit different than Firstname Lastname eh?

Comment: Please help us out a little here.  What are the URLs?  Do you control the content of these URLs?  Thanks, ~Ray

Comment: Why don't you use sessions for that?

Comment: You're asking for a method to run arbitrary code on a client browser (presumably that you don't control, with code that's a little unfriendly sounding). You do realize that's a security right, right? You could cURL or see if a headless browser could be used to automate obtaining the file and submitting. But the whole setup sounds odd.

Comment: @RayPaseur For perhaps obvious reasons i do not wish to provide the URLs, i do control the content of the page with text, however i do not control the content of the page with the form, im sure there is omething simple that i am looking over here.

Comment: @JaredFarrish this isnt for any sort of injection, i just have information that i need to carry over into someone elses form, and i have to do this often. so i would love to write a script to do this

Comment: You control the content of the page with the paragraph tags?  But you do not control the content of the form.  You want to make an automated POST of the form, adding in values for Username and Password.  Does that sum it up correctly?

Comment: @RayPaseur you nailed it

Comment: You can use CURL with a GET-method request to read the HTML from the foreign web site.  Then you can parse the HTML with PHP to isolate the form input controls and create a raw POST string.  Following that you can use CURL POST to send the data to the "action" script.  Your PHP script will need to act like a well-behaved web browser, accepting and returning cookies, following redirects, etc.  When I have done this in the past I have found it to require a VERY long period for debugging, so build that into your plans.  A much better way would be to contact the owners of that site and get an API.

Comment: @RayPaseur is there anyway, once i get the information to the form on the other server, that i can incorporate JS etc to add the information into the form? i know in some cases you can run JS out of the url bar. can i do this by passing JS in php GET?

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  JavaScript is not in play here; it is only a server-to-server communication.  You will parse the form in the foreign web page.  When you know the names of the HTML input controls your PHP script will be able to use those names and your predefined values to create a raw post string, and post it to the foreign server.  If this sounds complicated and hard to do, well, that's because it is complicated and hard to do. That's why I recommend asking for an API.  If the owners of the foreign site want you to have automated access to their server, they will provide the API.

Comment: @RayPaseur i just got this finished just as you had said i should. it works perfect. if you want to put an answer in the answer section, ill give you pest anser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, You Me:

You can use CURL with a GET-method request to read the HTML from the foreign web site. Then you can parse the HTML with PHP to isolate the form input controls and create a raw POST string. Following that you can use CURL POST to send the data to the "action" script. Your PHP script will need to act like a well-behaved web browser, accepting and returning cookies, following redirects, etc. When I have done this in the past I have found it to require a VERY long period for debugging, so build that into your plans. A much better way would be to contact the owners of that site and get an API.

All the best for the New year 2013, ~Ray

Answer (score 0):

You could use this in page1.php.

```
<form action="Page2.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" /><br />
<input type="text" name="Password" id="Password" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Transfer Information" />

</form>
```

Page2.php contains:

```
<?php 
$Username = $_POST[Username];
$Password = $_POST[Password];
?>
<p>Username="<?php echo $Username; ?>"</p>
<p>Password="<?php echo $Password; ?>"</p>
```